# JD-Eclipse failed to install on my Eclipse 3.7

Tags: java, decompiler

I tried to install JD-Eclipse, I love the JD standalone tools but I need to debug something on Eclipse and I was hoping this would help me decompile some classes for which I don't have the source code.
The p2 installation failed with this error:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
>   session context was:(profile=e24e8d3741426860a79f62d4553b8181, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
>   Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,jd.ide.eclipse,0.1.3.
>   http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar
>   Artifact not found: osgi.bundle,jd.ide.eclipse.macosx.x86_64,0.1.3.
>   http://java.decompiler.free.fr/jd-eclipse/update/plugins/jd.ide.eclipse.macosx.x86_64_0.1.3.jar

You can install the exact same eclipse as mine using this yoxos profile: https://yoxos.eclipsesource.com/userdata/profile/e24e8d3741426860a79f62d4553b8181

Any idea what's the cause of my problem?

Answer (score 10):

Maybe this update site is not available now.
You can download from mirror site.
http://jd.benow.ca/jd-eclipse/downloads/jdeclipse_update_site.zip

Comment: Thank for your answer but I did try to install from the update site zip file before posting here with the exact same error.
So this is not it.

Comment: Using the zip worked for me, but I'm on windows and it looks like you're on a mac.  I'm surprised this isn't working for you because the files it's complaining about (jd.ide.eclipse_0.1.3.jar and jd.ide.eclipse.macosx.x86_64_0.1.3.jar) are in the zip.

Answer (score 10):

In case is of use to someone - I had this issue on Win XP - tried both the update site and then installing from downloaded Archive - the original poster's problem was present in both cases.  Exploding the zip and then using the 'Local' option to point to the exploded archive's directory allowed the plugin to install successfully.

Comment: Thanks @jc1001 - this solved an identical problem for me too.

Comment: @SeB.Fr: If this answer solved your problem, you should accept it. You (and only you, as the person who posted the question) can do so by selecting the check-mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the answers did not work for me. My solution is unzipping the file given in the previous answer, modifiying the site.xml file to point the directory of where I unzip it.

It like the below for my local:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
   <description url="C:\Users\username\Downloads\jdeclipse_update_site">
      Eclipse Update Site for Java Decompiler Plug-in
   </description>
   <feature url="features/jd.edi.eclipse.feature_0.1.3.jar" id="jd.edi.eclipse.feature" version="0.1.3">
      <category name="JD-Eclipse"/>
   </feature>
   <category-def name="JD-Eclipse" label="Java Decompiler Eclipse Plug-in"/>
</site>
```

And lastly, go to your eclipse, **help -> add new software** paste your local link (C:\Users\username\Downloads\jdeclipse_update_site) to **Work with** input text, press **Enter**.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you that worked! Just one clarification make sure help -> add new software -> Add -> Local, to select the folder on your c drive, otherwise you will get error "Schema not supported".